# Failure parsing JSON error with Laravel 6 and Fullcalendar 4

Tags: ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I have the following script in the blade.php:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var SITEURL = "{{url('/dash')}}";
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,'
        },
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        editable: true,
        navLinks: true,
        events: SITEURL + "/calendar",
        displayEventTime: true,
        defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                event.allDay = true;
            } else {
                event.allDay = false;
            }
        },
```

And in the controller this part which is get the events from the database:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax()) {
        $returnedColumns = ['id', 'title', 'start', 'end'];

        $start = (!empty($request->start)) ? ($request->start) : ('');
        $end = (!empty($request->end)) ? ($request->end) : ('');

        $events = Event::whereBetween('start', [$start, $end])->get($returnedColumns);

        return response()->json($events);
    }

    return view('/dash/calendar');
}
```

The Json looks like this, if I remove the `if(request()->ajax()) {` part:

[{"id":347,"title":"Unavailable","start":"2020-02-11 06:00:00","end":"2020-02-11 06:30:00"}]

Seems the request working fine, but I got JSON parse error, and the calendar just won't show the events. What could be a problem?

[image]

Comment: You can call the controller via its route in the browser. This will show you the JSON response or the full error.

Comment: Of course i defined the routes:
Route::get('/dash/calendar','FullCalendarController@index');
Route::post('/dash/calendar/create','FullCalendarController@create');
Route::post('/dash/calendar/update','FullCalendarController@update');
Route::post('/dash/calendar/delete','FullCalendarController@destroy');

Comment: As you see in your image, you don't receive JSON but HTML. This contains the error stack trace. Go ahead and console.log() the response in your JS to get the full output.

Comment: As a separate issue, `eventRender: function (event, element, view) {` is not correct in fullCalendar 4. This will cause errors when you eventually get your event feed working. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender to get the correct function signature.

Comment: Anyway, in this `public function index`... why are you trying to the handle the JSON output inside the same controller action as you use to return the main view? There's no need for that. Just create a separate function for it in your controller. A dual purpose function which sometimes returns a view and sometimes returns JSON is a bit crazy, and unnecessary. Each function should do one clear job, and do it well. I can't see any reason for it to be a hybrid. It could well be contributing to the issue (seeing as the main symptom is that it's returning HTML instead of JSON!).

Comment: ADyson, I just separated the 2 function and seems it working, but I don't really understand the problem. Anyway thank you the you mentioned it!

Comment: I would guess probably the reason it didn't work before was that `if(request()->ajax()) {` wasn't a reliable test, and therefore it always returned the HTML view instead of the JSON. So that's one reason (apart from good design principles) to have separate functions for each task.